# Composition of Pseudodifferential Operators - Remainder term of Asymptotic Expansion

Tags: taylor-expansion, pseudo-differential-operators

first off this is my first time posting here so I am only learning how to format questions. Please bear with me.

I am trying to prove the asymptotic expansion for the symbol of the composition of two pseudodifferential operators (of class $S_{1,0}$). The expansion itself I have found but I am having trouble with the remainder term. Supposing $p(x,\xi)$ and $q(x,\xi)$ are symbols of order $m_1$ and $m_2$ respectively (meaning $|D_x^\beta D_\xi^\alpha \,p(x,\xi)|\le C_{\alpha,\beta}\,(1+|\xi|)^{m_1-|\alpha|}$ and similarly for $q(x,\xi)$). I need to show $$|D_x^\beta D_\xi^\alpha \,R_N(x,\xi)|\le C_{\alpha,\beta}\,(1+|\xi|)^{m_1+m_2-|\alpha|-N}$$ for any $N\gt 0$. This remainder term is given by $$R_N(x,\xi)=\int r_N(x,\xi,\eta) \,\widehat{q(\eta,\xi)}\,e^{ix\eta}\,d\eta $$ where $r_N(x,\xi,\eta)$ is the integral form of the remainder from Taylor's Theorem: $$r_N(x,\xi,\eta)=\sum_{|\delta|=N}\frac{N}{\delta !}\; \eta^\delta \;\int_0^1(1-t)^N\,D_\xi^\delta \,p(x,\xi+t\eta)\,dt $$

Applying Leibniz rule we get $$|D_x^\beta D_\xi^\alpha\,R_N(x,\xi)|\le\int|D_x^\beta D_\xi^\alpha [r_N(x,\xi,\eta)\, \widehat{q(\eta,\xi)}\,e^{ix\eta}\,]|d\eta $$ $$\le \int \sum_{\lambda \le \alpha} \sum_{\mu \le \beta}|D_x^\mu D_\xi^\lambda\,r_n(x,\xi,\eta)|\;|D_\xi^{\alpha-\lambda}\,\widehat{q(\eta,\xi)}|\;|D_x^{\beta-\mu}\,e^{ix\eta}|\,d\eta $$

Assuming $q(x,\xi)$ has compact support in $x$, using integration by parts we get the estimate $$|D_\xi^{\alpha-\lambda}\,\widehat{q(\eta,\xi)}|\le C_{M,\alpha,\lambda} \frac{(1+|\xi|)^{m_2-|\alpha-\lambda|}}{(1+|\eta|)^M}$$ for any $M\ge 0$. So what is left is estimates for $r_n(x,\xi,\eta)$. We get $$ |D_x^\mu D_\xi^\lambda\,r_n(x,\xi,\eta)|\le C_N \; |\eta|^N \sum_{|\delta|=N} max_{\,t\in [0,1]} |D_x^\mu D_\xi^{\lambda+\delta}\,p(x,\xi+t\eta)|  $$ $$ \le C_{N,\mu,\delta,\lambda} \; |\eta|^N \sum_{|\delta|=N} max_{\,t\in [0,1]} (1+|\xi+t\eta|)^{m_1-|\lambda+\delta|}$$

From here the idea is to split the integral in two parts for $|\eta|\le |\xi|/2$ and the rest. The rest is fine and I get the desired bound for that part taking $M$ large enough. The trouble is with the first part. Using that $|\eta|\le |\xi|/2$ then we can get the bound
$$ |D_x^\mu D_\xi^\lambda\,r_n(x,\xi,\eta)|\le C_{N,\mu,\delta,\lambda} \; |\eta|^N \sum_{|\delta|=N}(1+|\xi|)^{m_1-|\lambda+\delta|}$$

Applying all of this gives (ignoring the other part of the integral which is well bounded)
$$|D_x^\beta D_\xi^\alpha \,R_N(x,\xi)|\le C_{} \sum_{\lambda \le \alpha} \sum_{|\delta|=N}(1+|\xi|)^{m_1+m_2-|\alpha-\lambda|-|\lambda+\delta|}\,\int_{|\eta| \le |\xi|/2} \frac {|\eta|^{\beta+N}}{(1+|\eta|)^M} d\eta$$

This integral is obviously converges and using triangle inequality in the exponent of $(1+|\xi|)$ gives

$$|D_x^\beta D_\xi^\alpha \,R_N(x,\xi)|\le C_{\alpha,\beta} \sum_{|\delta|=N}(1+|\xi|)^{m_1+m_2-|\alpha+\delta|}$$

So finally (this seems long winded) I have arrived at my problem. Since $-|\alpha+\delta| \ge -|\alpha| - |\delta| = -|\alpha| - N$, I don't end up getting my desired bound.

I wrote a lot down, possibly unnecessarily but I am going mad thinking it is something very obvious I am missing. Can anyone spot my mistake?? Also please let me know if my formatting needs work.

Cheers!

Comment: it's a long time since I thought about this stuff. You might find my lecture notes on arxiv useful. Shubin's book is very careful and detailed. One trick with this sort of argument that might work is to take a bigger value of $N$ just for working out the estimate for a particular value of $|\alpha|.$

Comment: Thank you. I was not aware of Shubin's book nor of your notes so these extra resources should help me in my study.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact I have found my error and it was very embarrassing, simply a matter of notation.

Of course $\alpha$ and $\delta$ are multi indices so the norm on them is not the euclidean norm. For multi indices we have obviously  $|\alpha + \delta|= |\alpha|+ |\delta|$ and so everything is just as it should be, triangle inequality does not come into play. I get my desired bound.

A brain fart cost me a few days.

Comment: Would you please accept this as an answer so that the question doesn't remained on the "Unanswered" list?